# jquery mobile - programmatically change radio button color

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using `jquery` to determine if a `jquery` mobile `radio` button has been selected. If  so I want to change the `background colour`. This successfully adds the the `checked` attribute:

```
if (row['cur']=="£") {
$('#cur2').attr('checked', 'checked');
}
```

but the `background color` doesn't change.

I've tried changing the css like this

```
$(".ui-radio:nth-child(1) .ui-radio-on span.ui-btn-inner").css('background-color', '#ffffff');
```

but that doesn't work either - any ideas please

Comment: _Why_ should setting a radio button to checked change its background color?

Comment: why not call `$('#cur2').css('background-color', '#ffffff');`

Comment: sorry I should have been more specific - it's the background colour of the button when the radio buttons are in a horizontal group - as here http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/radiobuttons/

Comment: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/74TT6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the next `<label>` and then its `<span>` children:

```
$('#cur2')
    .next('label')
    .children('span')
    .css('background-color', 'red');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7q8R/)

Comment: @PhilBarnett it works in the demo, so what are you doing differently? If possible, post a fiddle that shows it not working

Comment: I have a multi-page jquery mobile layout. I can successfully replicate what  you've done if I put the radio group on the first page and trigger your jquery code using body onload. However my radio group needs to go on the second page > I've tried to trigger it with $('#quote').live('pagecreate',function(event){
 //// 
}); - it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh the checkbox/radio button when you change it programatically.

```
$('#cur2').prop('checked',true).checkboxradio('refresh');
```